# How to use C# Regular Expression to get the match number list?

Tags: c#

```
string inputText = "abc13500008888,   *a1c13688886666abc   mm13565685555**" ;
```

How to use C# Regular Expression to get the match number list?

The rule is that is a 11 continuous number and the first letter is 1.

The results should be:

```
13500008888
13688886666
13565685555
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the numbers are always 11 digits starting with 1, you can just do

```
Regex.Matches(inputText, @"1\d{10}");
```

If you want to match other lengths as well, you can either use `+` for one or more or `{min,}` where `min` is the minimum number of digits you want to match.

Answer (score 1):

[Regex.Matches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches.aspx)(input, @"\d+");

Comment: This will match the single 1s as well.

Comment: @Brian Rasmussen: Well spotted

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Matches(input, @"1\d{10}");
```